# Wordpress Hide Social media sharing links

Tags: css, wordpress

I am using this theme in Wordpress

[Click Mag](http://preview.themeforest.net/item/click-mag-viral-wordpress-news-magazineblog-theme/full_screen_preview/18081003?_ga=2.83035734.1905314672.1505582853-1940541719.1505582853). This theme has a built in functionality which shows sharing options for multiple social media platforms. I would like to hide that for a particular page. Is there any option for that?

I know I can write page specific css but I was thinking if there is any other nice way to do it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways to do it.

Add an inline CSS, that corresponds to that page

```
body.your-page-id #mvp-nav-soc { 
     display: none; 
}
```

You can also do it with PHP, but not recommended as it increases server load

```
<?php  ?>
<?php if( in_page('your_page') ) { ?>
<style>
  #mvp-nav-soc{
      display: none;
  }
</style>
<?php } ?>
```